# Вывод кол-во раз char * какой-то int

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь сделать следующие,

в зависимости от числа `StringPos`, добавлять кол-во пробелов `space` перед `b`

```
char space[] = " ";
char b[] = "B";

for(int i = 0; i < StringPos; i++)
{
   //вывод на экран
   Test_value->VaString((space * i) + b);
}
```

к сожалению это так не работает ибо умножать char нельзя. Знает кто правильный способ?

Comment: `cout << " ";` в цикле.. после цикла `cout << b << endl;`

Comment: Если вам нужно вывести количество пробелов равное `StringPos` то в том же цикле вместо умножения используйте просто `cout << space;`. И да, зачем вы объявили `space` и `b` как массивы?

Comment: Можно ещё хитрым образом memset' ом массив набить пробелами, чтоб обойтесь вообще без цикла, цикл довольно накладной..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Все просто:

```
Test_value->VaString(std::string(i, ' ') + b); // Или `+ "B"`.
```

Если параметр этой функции - это `const char *`, а не `std::string`, тогда так:

```
Test_value->VaString((std::string(i, ' ') + b).c_str());
```

Comment: я просто не внимательно прочитал: все правильно

Comment: а если у меня `char eins[] = "1";` то `Test_value->VaString((BuchstabenStr.str() + eins).c_str());` не будет работать, как быть?

Comment: @Insider Что возвращает `BuchstabenStr.str()`? Если `const char *`, тогда попробуйте `Test_value->VaString((std::string(BuchstabenStr.str()) + eins).c_str());`.

Comment: `BuchstabenStr` у меня `std::stringstream`

Comment: @Insider В таком случае то, что вы написали, уже должно работать. Можно текст ошибки?

Comment: я забыл в одном месте ; к сожалению мой редактор ничего мне такого не показывает.. поэтому текста ошибки не было. Я реши, спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 2):

Если Вам известно максимальное количество пробелов, то заводите константную строку из этого максимального количества, а выводите ее часть, например:

```
const std::string s20="                   ";
std::cout << s20.substr(0, 11) << "B";
```

или

```
char s20[] = "                   ";
std::cout << (s20 + 9) << "B";
```

во втором случае выведется 20-9 пробелов.

Answer (score 1):

Пример как набить массив пробелами и вывести на экран:

```
char space[100] = {0};
memset(space, ' ', (StringPos - 1));
cout << space << b << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

можно еще использовать фишку из си

```
printf("%*s", StringPos, b);
```

Если не ошибаюсь именно так.

Comment: Этот конструктив лопнет сразу :) по тому что он планирует напечатать количество байт равное `StringPos` из массива `b`, а там, как мы видим один символ и завершение строки :) память испортите.

Comment: @NewView чего? Можно поподробнее, а то я что-то я не понял

Comment: Ну вроде написал сверху, попробуйте это в тестовом коде. Принцип '.*' это печатать столько то байтов из следующей переменной, и если на то пошло, должно быть не `℅*c` а `℅.*s` с учётом что там массив char.

Comment: @NewView слушайте, не надо ничего от себя придумывать: написано %*  - а не %.* - это разные случаи

Comment: @NewView единственно что нужно исправить, это добавить к StringPos количество символов в строке - вот это да